# Controlling "Dji Phantom 4" from a computer

Tags: dji-sdk

As a part of a research project, we've bought the phantom 4 and we would like to control it from a PC not a mobile phone, Is there any direct way to control it from a computer or any indirect way to control it from a computer through a mobile app/emulator?

Any details will be highly helpful and appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

DJI does not have a PC SDK yet. You could write a Mobile app to communicate with PC app through LTE or local Wifi to control the drone.

Answer (score 0):

**Info** DJI Phantom series is only supported by [DJI Mobile SDK](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/).

**Possible solution** You could implement a mobile app that communicates with a backend. This way you can control the aircraft using the backend.

**Important hint** iOS devices work/communicate better with the drone.